# Split duration per time interval

Tags: google-bigquery

My data:
The length of a shift is broken down per `time` interval of 1 hour (e.g. 19:00:00 represents the time interval 19:00:00-20:00:00)

| date | time | duration_in_hours | shift_start_at | shift_end_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-24 | 19:00:00 | 3 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 20:00:00 | 3 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 21:00:00 | 3 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 22:00:00 | 3 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |

Expected outcome:
Split `duration_in_hours` per `time` interval

| date | time | duration_in_hours | shift_start_at | shift_end_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-24 | 19:00:00 | 0.5 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 20:00:00 | 1 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 21:00:00 | 1 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |
| 2022-05-24 | 22:00:00 | 0.5 | 19:30:00 | 22:30:00 |

Query used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
date,
TIME(hour, 0, 0) AS time,
duration in hours,
shift_start_at,
shift_end_at,
FROM a, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23)) hour
WHERE TIME(hour, 0, 0) >= TIME_TRUNC(shift_start_at, HOUR) AND TIME(hour, 0, 0) < shift_end_at
```

I have used the same query for a different table and it splits the `duration_in_hours` automatically. It doesn't do the job here and I don't understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information to calculate `duration_in_hours` exists in the same row, so I think you can make it with simple math using `CASE` expression.

Consider below:

```sql
   CASE WHEN start_at > time THEN 1 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_at) / 60
        WHEN TIME_DIFF(end_at, time, MINUTE) < 60 THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_at) / 60
        ELSE 1
   END AS duration_in_hours
```

output:

[image]

Comment: What approach would you suggest when the shift ends at or after "00:00:00"? I have tried to create a condition based on the date (for example `CASE WHEN time_date > date AND`...) without success

Comment: @Fabien, do you mean `end_at` is the time of next day like `start_at` is `19:30:00` and `end_at` is `00:00:00` or `01:30:00` ?

Comment: Yes exactly! When `end_at` lands at `00:00:00` or after `00:00:00` like `01:30:00` for example.

Comment: @Fabien hard to suggest something until I see the sample data having that kind data, but you seem to change `time` calcuation to `datetime`  caluation.  Anyway since it'll be different problem from your orginal question. You'd better post another question with new sample data so that  I or other community member help you further.

Comment: Yes, I changed to `datetime` in order to condition on the date.
Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203176/split-duration-per-time-interval-if-shift-ends-at-midnight-or-after-midnight