# Split duration per time interval if shift ends at midnight or after midnight

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery

Each employee has a unique user ID which is `emp_id`. One of the employee has a shift on the `2023-05-07` starting at `19:32:00` and ending at `01:19:00` the next day.

Results from my query:

| date | emp_id | time_shift | duration_in_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 19:00:00 | 0.47 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 20:00:00 | 0.32 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 21:00:00 | 0.32 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 22:00:00 | 0.32 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 23:00:00 | 0.32 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 00:00:00 | 0.47 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 01:00:00 | 0.47 |

Expected outcome:

| date | emp_id | time_shift | duration_in_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 19:00:00 | 0.47 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 20:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 21:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 22:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 23:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 01:00:00 | 0.32 |

For some reason, the `duration_in_hours` for the `time_shift` at and over midnight takes the same `duration_in_hours` value as the one of `shift_start` and all the `time_shift` where `duration_in_hours` should be equal to 1 get the `duration_in_hours` from `shift_end`.

I have tried all kind of conditions, using the `date` from the generated timestamp which is different after midnight or to transform `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` for example.

Note: A wider date range does not help.

Do you know how to fix it or maybe a work-around?

Query sample:

```
    With shift AS (SELECT DISTINCT
    date, 
    emp_id,
    TIME(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM generated_timestamp),0,0) AS time_shift,
    shift_start, --datetime
    shift_end, --datetime
      FROM `shift_data`,    UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array(timestamp_trunc(timestamp(shift_start),hour), timestamp(shift_end), INTERVAL 1 hour)) generated_timestamp
      WHERE 
        date BETWEEN "2023-05-07" AND "2023-05-07"
        )
    
    SELECT
    date,
    emp_id,
    time_shift,
    -- Split duration per hour interval
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN EXTRACT(TIME FROM shift_start) > time_shift THEN 1 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM shift_start) / 60
          WHEN TIME_DIFF(EXTRACT(TIME FROM shift_end), time_shift, MINUTE) < 60 THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM shift_end) / 60
          ELSE 1
        END
      ) AS duration_in_hours
    FROM shift
    WHERE emp_id = 123
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

| date | emp_id | shift_start | shift_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-07 | 123 | 2023-05-05 17:32:04.529479 UTC | 2023-05-05 23:19:07.127184 UTC |

Comment: Hi - please update your question to show the relevant source data that you are using

Comment: Hi, what do you mean?

Comment: The shift_data table that you are querying with sample data

Comment: @NickW Added the sample at the very bottom. The timestamps are in UTC in the table. I convert them to the right timezone (UTR+2) in my query.

Answer (score 2):

Hope below gives you some direction for your problem.

```sql
DECLARE shift_start DEFAULT DATETIME '2023-05-07 19:32:00';
DECLARE shift_end DEFAULT DATETIME '2023-05-08 01:19:00';

WITH shift_data AS (
  SELECT shift_start,
         shift_end,
         DATETIME_TRUNC(shift_start, HOUR) shift_start_hour,
         DATETIME_TRUNC(shift_end, HOUR) shift_end_hour,
         DATETIME_TRUNC(shift_start, HOUR) + INTERVAL elapsed HOUR AS time_shift,
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, DATETIME_DIFF(shift_end, shift_start, HOUR))) elapsed
)
SELECT DATE(time_shift) date,
       '123' emp_id,
       TIME(time_shift) time_shift,
       shift_start,
       shift_end,
       CASE
         WHEN shift_start_hour = shift_end_hour THEN DATETIME_DIFF(shift_end, shift_start, MINUTE) / 60
         WHEN shift_start_hour = time_shift THEN 1 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM shift_start) / 60
         WHEN shift_end_hour = time_shift THEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM shift_end) / 60
         ELSE 1
       END AS duration_in_hours  
  FROM shift_data;
```

**Query result**

[image]